# Redirects with A3M for Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-a3m

I've been battling with redirects after users log in.

The redirect is encoded into the URL. For example:

http://demo.a3m.local:8090/account/sign_in/?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fdemo.a3m.local%3A8090%2Faccount%2Faccount_settings

On this demo install it works perfectly.

However on a development site it seems to double encode the url so it becomes:

http://dev.mysite.local:8090/account/sign_in?continue=http%253A%252F%252Fdev.mysite.local%253A8090%252Faccount%252Faccount_profile

Forward slash is encoded to %3A and then further to %253

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Typical - struggle for days and as soon as you ask the question one works it out.

It was my .htaccess file rewriting the URL.

Used the No-Escape flag to fix it: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne